# how can i store data in RDD which cannot reside in spark memory.

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This question might be too basic , but am kinda stuck on it .
I want to **process two Hive table data in Spark using Data frame** , but the data in hive table is too big for Spark RDD to hold it , I know if i load whole data at once in RDD it will degrade Spark performance , so what can be done in this case ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: " I know if i load whole data at once in RDD it will degrade Spark performance" Eh? That's what an RDD is for. You're going to have to explain what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul 

Isnt it so? when we load whole data which RDD cannot store in memory , it spill rest of the data to Disk , And reading from disk is time consuming , if this is not the case , kindly correct me .

Comment: It will spill to disk but it will be clever and spill as little as possible. No matter what technology you use it will have to store it on disk while works on it. This is what pagefiles and swap space are for. The vast majority of spark I write uses more data than the cluster can store in memory. Its fine.

Comment: And we're not going to be able to offer any better answers until you tell us more about what you're doing.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul , I am fetching 2 table data from hive and performing the join operation based on the primary key , after getting whole data i further need to filter it out.